# Format and parsing of windows ini files

Tags: .net, parsing, configuration-files, ini, file-format

I'm currently working on a Windows project and I need to modify its ini config files.  I never worked with ini files before but have seen they have a similar format across different projects.

Is the format defined somewhere (say by Microsoft?) and is there some widely used library (.NET?) to parse it?  Where can I find more information on how it is parsed, and how to access the configuration data in my code?

I'm trying to find out what library, if any, my current project is using.  Are there any keywords like "System.Config" I can search for?  What I have already figured out is that the keys for the inis seem to be defined by a [bond](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond).

Comment: ive used this before - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C

Comment: Thanks for the link @Ctznkane525.  I'm looking for a way to find out what my current project is using instead of using a new library to parse the existing config files.

Comment: your source code will be pointing to a specific ini file...you can open that file in a text editor...the format is defined...and ive given you a reference to a library to parse it

Answer (score 0):

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), the format is not well defined.  What all ini files have in common may be only keys, sections and semicolon comments.  It is highly probably that my project is using its own format and parser.